# Cannot connect device with nRF8001 Bluetooth LE to Windows 10 PC

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-leonardo, uart, windows

I've built a device using an IMUduino board, which is supposed to be similar to Arduino Leonardo board with a nRF8001 bluetooth. I was able to connect my device to an Android phone using the nRF UART v2.0 app, I tested some examples and it worked with success.

I would like to connect the device to a Windows 10 PC via bluetooth. I have installed the driver of the nRF8001, and I am able to pair both PC-UART. However, when I open the Master control Panel, I cannot find any Master emulator, the menu is empty. Master control panel version is 3.10.0.14.

Is there any way to connect a device with nRF8001 to a Windows 10 PC?

Thanks.